# Multitenant database vs multiple databases

Tags: database, asp.net-core, multi-tenant

We are developing a new version of a SAAS web application using ASP.NET Core 6.

This is a multitenant app. With a single app we serve several clients (tenants). On each request we check the domain to get the corresponding tenant. For this current version we have a database per tenant and a MASTER database in which we have the tenant list and some shared data. This is working great and the app is working fast.

The problem is all the tenants are sharing some data. For example they have events and we need to do a search of all events from all tenants. Also, a user can be in multiple tenants, so in the MASTER database we have all users and every time a useris changed in a tenant, we have to update that user not only in the MASTER database but also in all tenant's databases that have that particular user. It is complicated but is working.

In the future version we think this could be a problem, since we are planning to increase tenants from 70 we have now to more than 2.000. Also, there is another problem, we are going to have free tenants that are going to use just a little functionallity and create a database for these clients doesn't sound like a good idea because we are going to end up with hundreds of databases that are not going to be used at all.

For this new version, we are thinking to have just one database for all of them. Having a TenantId in all shared tables and having the filter by tenant in the DataContext by default so we don't mix tenant's data. This won't be a problem for us.

We are worried about having a huge database that slows all down.
Each year every tenant's data grows, since they do events. At this moment, after 3 years using this app, a big tenant database size is around 500MB and a regular one less than 100MB. Each tenant database has 161 tables and some of the tables have more than 500K records, but in those cases the data stored is mainly integers.

Would it be better to have just one database or we should keep having multiple?
Having multiple is going to be more complicated because we are starting to do global searchs so we are going to need more data duplicated in the master database. But ee are worried about performance with just one database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500 MB is pretty small size for a database. If the growth is going to be linear like this, you'll be fine with single database, if you're going to have shared data. With proper indexes, you wouldn't need to worry about performance, unless you're reaching more than 100 GBs of data. But you should have flexibility for separate databases too (which I think you've), since some clients might want their data not to be shared.

Comment: Clients are not aware where their data is, and their data is not "completely" shared. In fact, if we reach 1.000 clients and having 500MB per client we are going to reach 100Gbs for sure if we succeed. Would it be possible to paginate or something similar if the single database is that big?

Comment: I would like to recommend using partitions for entities like events, where your events in certain range are stored in a shard. The query engine is going to pickup some range like dates and identify the shards, then query against the shards, this helps scale out and also smaller footprint / shard. There are options like `ElasticSearch` where you can build a in memory collection that can be searched and based on the results, you find the shards and aggregate the results.